# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Idiom::months()

Tags: php, oop

I've recently started to get more interested in OOP so I tried to implement it on my new project.

The point of the class Idiom is to help me get all the idiom and translation information faster.

My class right now looks like this:

```
class Idiom
{
    var $idiom;

    public function setIdiom($newIdiom)
    {
        $this->idiom = $newIdiom;
    }

    public function getIdiom()
    {
        return $this->idiom;
    }

    public function month($idiom, $month)
    {
        switch ($idiom) {
            case 'pt':
                switch ($month) {
                    case 'January':
                        $chosen_month = 'Janeiro';
                        break;
                    case 'February':
                        $chosen_month = 'Fevereiro';
                        break;
                    case 'March':
                        $chosen_month = 'Março';
                        break;
                    case 'April':
                        $chosen_month = 'Abril';
                        break;
                    case 'May':
                        $chosen_month = 'Maio';
                        break;
                    case 'June':
                        $chosen_month = 'Junho';
                        break;
                    case 'July':
                        $chosen_month = 'Julho';
                        break;
                    case 'August':
                        $chosen_month = 'Agosto';
                        break;
                    case 'September':
                        $chosen_month = 'Setembro';
                        break;
                    case 'October':
                        $chosen_month = 'Outubro';
                        break;
                    case 'November':
                        $chosen_month = 'Novembro';
                        break;
                    case 'December':
                        $chosen_month = 'Dezembro';
                        break;
                }
                break;
        }
        return $chosen_month;
    }
}
```

Which I access using this piece of code:

```
for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
    $month = date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$m, 1, date('Y')));
    $idiom = new Idiom();
    echo '<option value="'.$m.'">'.$idiom->months('pt',$month).'</option>';
}
```

But I have also tried using this method instead:

```
for ($m=1; $m<=12; $m++) {
    $month = date('F', mktime(0,0,0,$m, 1, date('Y')));
    echo '<option value="'.$m.'">'.Idiom::months('pt',$month).'</option>';
}
```

But both of them trigger the error: Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method Idiom::months().

I'm currently running PHP 7.2.0 on Xampp.
The guide I followed to achieve this was: https://www.killerphp.com/tutorials/php-objects-page-1/

Thanks for your help and suggestions, those are very welcomed as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo error. the public method you defined in your class is month and not months. `public function month($idiom, $month){}`